# Pytest DynamoDB client.describe_continuous_backups returns error

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, tdd, pytest

I am trying to test if a newly created table has continuous backups enabled.
I am using Python and pytest as follows:

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb', environ['REGION'])

backup_status = client.describe_continuous_backups(TableName=logs_table_name)['ContinuousBackupDescription']['PointInTimeRecoveryDescription']['PointInTimeRecoveryStatus']
    
assert backup_status == 'ENABLED'
```

When the test runs it returns below error

```
    @amzn_request_id
    def call_action(self):
        self.body = json.loads(self.body or "{}")
        endpoint = self.get_endpoint_name(self.headers)
        if endpoint:
            endpoint = camelcase_to_underscores(endpoint)
>           response = getattr(self, endpoint)()
E           AttributeError: 'DynamoHandler' object has no attribute 'describe_continuous_backups'
```

Tried to google it but no luck, also I have a similar code in another project and it works ok.
Anyone had something like that in the past?

Comment: Please provide the code you want to test.

Comment: Hi @slideshowp2 thank you for replying. I was using obsolete version of moto that did not have the describe_continuous_backups fully available yet, this is now resolved by upgrading to moto 1.3.16

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.
The describe_continuous_backups was not available in moto 1.3.14, updating it to 1.3.16 resolved it.